# How to Create a Load Instruction in LLVM, given Pointer to do the Load from?

Tags: c++, llvm

I'm writing a LLVM pass where I create a function with integer pointer arguments. I need to implement the body of the function as well, and in order to do so, I need the integer values that are being pointed to. I am trying to create a load instruction that I can insert at the end of the basic block that contains the function body, but I am getting an error when doing so. Things compile fine, but when I run the pass, I get a generic error.

From what I've found about LLVM, there are usually ways to create instructions that don't involve using constructors, but I couldn't find a way to do that for load instructions, so I just used one of the constructors instead. After creating the function with arguments of the integer pointer type, this is the code that I'm using to do the load:

```
llvm::LoadInst operandLoad(llvm::Type::getInt32Ty(ctx), argList[0], "test", basicBlock);
```

If I comment the above line out, my pass runs fine. I'm unsure whether this is enough to diagnose the issue, so I'll include all the code to create the function (it's slightly simplified):

```
void createFunction(std::string functionName, llvm::LLVMContext &ctx, llvm::Module *module) {
        std::vector<llvm::Type*> typeList = {llvm::Type::getInt32PtrTy(ctx)};

        // Create function type
        llvm::FunctionType *functionType = llvm::FunctionType::get(llvm::Type::getVoidTy(ctx), typeList, false);

        // Create function
        llvm::Function *function = llvm::Function::Create(functionType, llvm::Function::ExternalLinkage, functionName, module);
        
        std::vector<llvm::Value*> argList;
        for (llvm::Function::arg_iterator it = function->arg_begin(); it != function->arg_end(); ++it) {
            argList.push_back(it);
        }

        llvm::BasicBlock *basicBlock = llvm::BasicBlock::Create(ctx, "entry", function);
        llvm::LoadInst operandLoad(llvm::Type::getInt32Ty(ctx), argList[0], "test", basicBlock);

        llvm::IRBuilder<> builder(ctx);
        builder.SetInsertPoint(basicBlock);
        builder.CreateRet(nullptr);
    }
```

I'm sure this is a stupid question, so sorry about that. And thanks in advance!

Comment: `llvm::LoadInst operandLoad(...)` is a declaration. Did you mean `llvm::LoadInst * operandLoad = new LoadInst(...)`?

Comment: Why aren't you using the `builder` object to create the load inst ??

Comment: Thanks @arrowd, that worked for me. I wasn't aware that I had to allocate memory in the heap to create these instructions and thought I could just declare them. And I see that in the `BinaryOperator::Create` method, heap allocation is being done in the way that you suggest in your answer.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, @droptop. That's probably something I should've tried prior to asking this question but didn't occur to me for some reason. I was wondering whether there was instruction on when I should be using `builder` as opposed to allocating heap memory when creating an instruction. Is it just a matter of preference?

Comment: "there are usually ways to create instructions that don't involve using constructors" is actually not true. Both approaches for creating instructions (insertion into the instruction list of a basic block and using `IRBuilder`) work by calling constructors.